# BRKR TASK has 10GB in tempdb

Tags: service-broker, tempdb

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64) 
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Millions of service broker conversations were not cleaned up properly and ended up using over 10GB in tempdb internal objects.

BRKR TASK  task_internal_objects_alloc_page_count : 2142768

Having cleaned them up with END CONVERSATION WITH CLEANUP, the conversations are gone from sys.conversation_endpoints, but the space in tempdb has not been released.

I was hoping some garbage clean up would kick in, but the space is still allocated to internal tasks 8 hours later.

Any tips on having this space released?

(Remus Resanu, help!)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at article "[A very strange Service Broker and TempDB problem](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/writeup-of-a-strange-service-broker-and-tempdb-problem/)".

Comment: Hello, thanks for the article, but it's not very helpful. alter database set new broker is not really an option. If you attempt that on an environment which has a ton of open conversations, you will lose them all ... and it takes a very long time to clean up 10gb from tempdb and generates a ton of blocking.  I don't have a problem with the keys, and sys.transmission_queue is empty.